# How can I add value to a reflected variable?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, reflection, field, system.reflection

I want to add value to a value I got through reflection. The += does not work and SetValue does not fit my needs. *

- Instance.Field does exist but this would not be good for my script(For reasons).

Here is my class:

```
public class OreMine : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] string VariableName;

    void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D col)
    {
        if(col.gameObject.tag == "Player")
        {
            var Value = typeof(Inventory).GetField(VariableName, BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Static);
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that I could not do this:

```
Value += 1
```

And this would not suit my needs:

```
public class OreMine : MonoBehaviour
{
valueField.SetValue(null, SomeInteger);
}
```

And in Microsoft documentation the AddValue seems like it's only for strings.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.serialization.serializationinfo.addvalue?view=net-8.0

Comment: Why are you using Reflection? Why are you tagging `Player` and where does the `Inventory` come up into this equation? Why aren't you using member variables and assigned game instances from the Inspector or `GetComponent()`? There are so many questions :) To me, there seems to be a problem in the design of your workflow. I have never seen any real need of Reflection in Unity where it could not be solved by proper design. Also, don't use `==` on tags, use `CompareTag()`.

Answer (score 0):

`Value += 1` is simply `Value = Value + 1`. If you're using reflection, you'll need a `GetValue`, a cast to the correct type from `object`, an increment, and a `SetValue` (which will have an implicit cast/box back to `object`). This ahs nothing to do with `AddValue`, which is a serialization concept.

Reflection is probably the worst way of approaching this problem, though. I might see whether adding an `ISomething` interface with a `void Increment()` or whatever method, so I can just go:

```
if (obj is ISomething typed)
    typed.Increment();
```

and have individual types worry about what that means.

Comment: @ReoCyan the first parameter to `GetValue` is the target instance; if the thing you want to read is a static field, you would pass `null`; if it is an instance field, you need to pass the object you want to read the field from. I don't know what your Inventory type looks like, so: you'll have to figure that out